# An inequality for graph nodes and edges

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that we have undirected simple graph $G=(V,E)$ (i.e. without loop), where $V$ is nodes and $E$ is edges.

I would like to prove that if $G$ has some cycle where its length is an even number, then $3|V| \geq 2|E|$.

Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete graph $K_n$ on $n \ge 5$ vertices has a cycle of even length, but $$3|V|=3n \not\ge n(n-1) = 2\binom{n}{2} = 2|E|.$$